# PartialFunction That Isn't Partial

Tags: scala

Is there a reason to use a `PartialFunction` on a function that's not partial?

```
scala> val foo: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
     | case x => x * 2
     | }
foo: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = <function1>
```

`foo` is defined as a `PartialFunction`, but of course the `case x` will catch all input.

Is this simply bad code as the `PartialFunction` type indicates to the programmer that the function is undefined for certain inputs?

Comment: Function vs Def type comparison (and PF using benefits): http://goo.gl/qNk7Lw

Comment: The scaladoc says: `function where the domain does not necessarily include all values of type A`. So it doesn't indicate what you say.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is, there are many examples of times when what you need to define on a trait/object/function definition is a `PartialFunction` but in reality the real implementation may not be one. Case in point, take a look at `def collect[B](f: PartialFunction[A,B])`:

```
val myList = thatList collect {
  case Right(value) => value
  case Left(other) => other.toInt
}
```

It's clearly not a "real" partial as it is defined for all input. That said, if I wanted to, I could just have the `Right` match.

However, if I were to have written `collect` as a full on plain function, then I'd miss out on the desired behavior (that is to be both a `filter` and a `map` rolled into one base on when a function is defined.) That's nice behavior and allows for a lot of flexibility when writing my own code.

So I guess the better question is, will you ever want behavior to reflect that a function might not be defined everywhere? If the answer is no, then don't do it.

Comment: I agree with your point, although I'm not sure about the example. If you pass a partial function that handles all cases into `collect`, then you might as well just use map as you are not filtering.

Comment: @theon that is true but without duplication, you can write one function and that's it. For a collection framework it helps that there are specialized functions like `collect` and `map` which overlap. For your own code, more generalized solutions which don't fall prey to violations of D-R-Y are preferred.

Answer (score 4):

There is no advantage in using a `PartialFunction` instead of a `Function`, but if you have to pass a `PartialFunction`, then you have to pass a `PartialFunction`.

Note that, because of the inheritance between these two, overloading a method to accept both results in something difficult to use, as the type inference won't work.

Comment: So you disagree then with Alexey's answer of enhanced readability with FPs - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21106829/409976?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Sure I do. He is plain wrong: using `match` statements is _not_ a characteristic of partial functions. If you write `def f: Int => Int = { case x => x + 1 }` and decompile it with javap, you'll see that the generated class is a `Function1`, with no `PartialFunction` methods.

Comment: The only remaining question is, Why is there no `ImpartialFunction`?

Answer (score 3):

`PartialFunction` literals allow pattern matching directly on arguments (e.g. `{ case (a, b) => ... }` instead of `_ match { case (a, b) => ... }`), which makes code more readable (see @wheaties' answer for another example).

EDIT: apparently this is wrong, see Daniel C. Sobral's comment on his answer. Not deleting, so that the comments still make sense.

Comment: You don't need a `PartialFunction` to match on literals. A `PartialFunction` is a `Function1` so pattern matching can work with a plain function too!

Comment: the spec 8.5 calls it a "pattern matching anonymous function", and depending on expected type, you explicitly get a Function or PF. It would be a service to correct the term here.